# How to implement data model in neo4j. Users, Questions, Answers

Tags: neo4j

I am new to neo4j and I need to make some kind of polling web application using neo4j.

User asks questions with several options for answer. User invites other users to answer this question. Users answer the question by choosing one or more options. It should be possible to query the results of a poll.

I've got 3 types of nodes: `User`, `Question`, `Option`.

First I was thinking about this model.

1. `(User)-[:ASKS]->(Question)`
2. `(Question)-[:INVITES]->(User)`
3. `(Question)-[:HAS]->(Option)`
4. `(User)-[:CHOOSES]->(Option)`

But in this case, if I need to get all questions that current user answered, I need to go from `User` to all `Options` that he chose (for all questions). And then figure out, which questions this user answered.

Then I thought about connecting `User` to `Question` instead of connecting `User` to `Answer`. The new relationship has an attribute that will store array of `Option` ids that user chose answering this question.

1. `(User)-[:ASKS]->(Question)`
2. `(Question)-[:INVITES]->(User)`
3. `(Question)-[:HAS]->(Option)`
4. `(User)-[:ANSWERS {optionIds: [...]}]->(Question)`

But here, It is difficult to make a query for poll results. (5 users chose option1, 2 users chose option2, ...). 
And it seems like storing id of a node inside another node/relationship is not a right way to do things in neo4j.

Now I'm thinking about doing this:

1. `(User)-[:ASKS]->(Question)`
2. `(Question)-[:INVITES]->(User)`
3. `(Question)-[:HAS]->(Option)`
4. `(User)-[:CHOOSES]->(Option)`
5. `(User)-[:ANSWERS]->(Question)`

Which way do you think is better? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not be too concerned about traversing just one additional relationship to get from a User to each of his answers. You could easily end up overcomplicating your model and your code. Not every query needs to be doable in a single step.

Option 2 is not "right way to do things" with a graph DB. Option 3 is adding redundancy and complexity. So, to me, your first option might be OK, depending on you use cases.

However, it is unintuitive to say that a "Question invites a User". Also, if you wanted to allow a single Question to have multiple askers and multiple invitees, you'd have no way of knowing which asker invited which invitee.

How about this model:

```
(:User)-[:SENDS]->(:Invitation)
(:Question)<-[:FOR]-(:Invitation)-[:TO]->(:User)
(:Question)-[:HAS]->(:Option)
(:User)-[:CHOOSES]->(:Option)
```

The Invitation node allows you to keep track of who asked whom which Question. Also, reading the relationships is more intuitive, and therefore more maintainable.

Answer (score -1):

The Below query will return you , Question, Option, and collection of user with respect to option
match
(asker:User)-[:asked]-(question:Question)-[:Has]-(o:Option)

with asker,question,option,nodes((o) -[:Answere] - ()))as asweredNodecollection
// Comment: asweredNodecollection above is two dimentional array, in 2nd dimentiona it contain two nodes, at index Zero option 0 and index one Answered user
return asker,question,collect({option:option, ansered:asweredNodecollection}) as output

And if you want to get all optioned choosed by Answered user to particular question then you can do something like this.
 match(asker:User)-[:asked]-(question:Question)-[:Has]-(o:Option)
 optional match (o) -[:Answer] - (aswereUser:User)
 return question,aswereUser,collect(o) as choosedoption